# How do I get Ubuntu to display permission errors when I forget sudo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I've recently started working on a server running Ubuntu 14.  Whenever I forget to use `sudo` for a command that requires elevated privileges, no permission errors are ever displayed.  This is especially troublesome when I try to restart Apache.  If I *forget* to use `sudo` I see

```
* Reloading web server apache2
*
```

with no error, which is *exactly* what I see when I *remember* to use `sudo`, with no fail/success message.  (Other systems I've used have always prompted for a password or displayed some sort of error if I lacked permission.)  This results in me pulling my hair out, wondering why changes to my Python application aren't showing up until I realize I forgot to use `sudo` to elevate my privileges.

Is there a configuration somewhere I can change to get permission errors to show?

Comment: What is the exact command you used? What is the output of `echo test >&2`?

Comment: I've used `service apache2 reload` but out of habit usually use `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`.  Either way, no-permission failure output is identical to success-with-sudo output.

`echo test >&2` outputs `test`.